# Wordpress/Javascript form not working on custom post type single posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

We are facing this weird behavior on our wordpress website. Below is a custom post type (hotel) post, as you can see everything loads perfectly and even the enquiry form is working fine with the input dates.

https://bubbleholidays.co/hotel/kandooma-maldives/

However, when you visit below new custom post type 'Holiday', enquiry form is not working anymore. I'm using the same template layout as the single_hotel.php layout with the single_holiday.php

https://bubbleholidays.co/holiday/escape-to-sun-island-resort/

I have tried enqueuing the scripts/styles but when I do that it just breaks, enqueuing is not working correctly.

Currently all the scripts are loaded on footer.php

Kindly please assist me to find the problem.

Best,

Comment: [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -> TLDR: **no**

Comment: When I visit the 2nd link I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: t.nextElementSibling is null`. This will break everything else. Always check the browser console first, especially before posting here

Comment: It's a css class error on the console, nothing to do with the form.

Comment: @reyno I have explained briefly on my question, Links are for reference, if you had read it carefully.